# How to remove js/jqzoom/jquery-1.3.1.min.js script in Magento Enterprise?

Tags: layout, magento

Can't remove js/jqzoom/jquery-1.3.1.min.js script in Magento EE 1.10.1.1 version.
This script is being added in app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/catalog.xml (around line 196).

Here is the code in my local.xml layout file:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jqzoom/jquery-1.3.1.min.js</name></action>
</catalog_product_view>
```

How can I remove this script without modifying core layout file? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jqzoom/jquery-1.3.1.min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```